Can Sons become Wali In Mother's Nikah according to the Shafi'i madhab?
AssalamAlaikum
A woman(38 year old approximately) whose husband was died appropriately 7 years ago. She Has 2 adult daughter and adult 2 Sons. She is Living in her husband's home who died.She Is Not depending on Father or bother .she totally depending on self. She And Her Sons earn for their living.
Now question is that if she wanna get married with a person and her sons and daughter are satisfied . Can son become wali of her Mother? She never wants to show next Nikah Due to society and relatives issues because regrettably in our society point out her this decesion in this age. Please Answer that . Can she make a secret marriage if sons become wali and two Muslims For Evidence. It will must valid and governmently registed Nikah. And Boy will also never show to his parents about this marriage.
If both Are Shafi'i then please is it w
Valid

Yes, if the mother doesn't have her father, or grandfather then he becomes the next wali

Who can be wali, and in what order? seems at least relevant, if not covering your inquiry, if you agree mark it as duplicate.

As per islamqa
jurists put possible walis in a certain order, and a wali who is more closely-related should not be ignored unless there is no such person or the relatives do not meet the specified conditions.
A woman’s wali is her father,
then whoever her father may have appointed before his death,
then her paternal grandfather or great-grandfather,
then her son, then his sons or grandsons,
then her brother through both parents (full brother),
then her brother through her father,
then the sons of her brother through both parents,
then the sons of her brother through her father,
then her uncle (her father’s brother through both parents),
then her father’s brother through the father,
then the sons of her father’s brother though both parents,
then the sons of her father’s brother through the father,
then whoever is more closely related, and so on – as is the case with inheritance.
The Muslim leader (or his deputy, such as a judge) is the wali for any woman who does not have a wali of her own.

According to the Shafi'is a son can not become the guardian of his mother for the purpose of marriage. Their reasoning is that guardianship belongs to a woman's father and after him to the relatives from her father's side who are his heirs. On the other hand her son belongs to the family\lineage of her husband,  so he is not in a position to represent her ancestral family.
An exception to this is when the son can become her guardian based on a right other than simply being her son, these include:

When the son is also her relative from her father's side. For example when she had been married to her cousin and so her son is also her uncle's grandson.
When the son is the ruler or a judge appointed by the ruler
When the son has guardianship over her due to freeing her from slavery etc.

Further: According to the Shafi'is a person can not act as a woman's guardian when a guardian of higher priority exists, is present and is eligible to be her guardian. According to the Shafi'is, the order of guardians for a free woman is as follows:

Father
Paternal ancestors  (grandfather, great grandfather and so on)
Brothers
Half brothers (from father's side)
Nephews (sons and further descendants of brothers and paternal half brothers)
Paternal Uncles
Paternal Cousins (son of uncle, grandson of uncle and so on)
Other male relatives who are related to the woman through her father, like her second cousins etc.
The ruler or a judge appointed by him

Ref:

ولا يزوج ابن ببنوة
A son cannot give his own mother in marriage solely by reason of being her son
— Mughni al-Muhtaaj


The stance of the Hanafis and Malikis and Hanbalis is that a son can become the guardian of his mother. They differ on the son's ranking in the list of guardians, some hold that he precedes the woman's father and ancestors, and some hold that he comes after them.
Among their evidence is the hadith:

فبعث إليها رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم عمر بن الخطاب يخطبها عليه فقالت أخبر رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أني امرأة غيرى وأني امرأة مصبية وليس أحد من أوليائي شاهد ‏.‏ فأتى رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فذكر ذلك له فقال ‏ "‏ ارجع إليها فقل لها أما قولك إني امرأة غيرى فسأدعو الله لك فيذهب غيرتك وأما قولك إني امرأة مصبية فستكفين صبيانك وأما قولك أن ليس أحد من أوليائي شاهد فليس أحد من أوليائك شاهد ولا غائب يكره ذلك ‏"‏ ‏.‏ فقالت لابنها يا عمر قم فزوج رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فزوجه
Then the Messenger of Allah sent 'Umar bin Al-Khattab with a proposal of marriage (to deliver to Umm Salamah).
She said: "Tell the Messenger of Allah that I am a jealous woman and that I have sons, and none of my guardians are present."
He went to the Messenger of Allah and told him that. He said: "Go back to her and tell her: As for your saying that you are a jealous woman, I will pray to Allah for you to take away your jealousy. As for your saying that you have sons, your sons will be taken care of. And as for your saying that none of your guardians are present, none of your guardians, present or absent, would object to that."
She said to her son: "O 'Umar, get up and perform the marriage to the Messenger of Allah," so he performed the marriage.
— Sunan Nasai

Here the son of Umm Salamah was her guardian and gave her in marriage to the Messenger of Allah ﵆.
However the Shafi'is have argued that the situation in the hadith is not analogous to the matter being discussed and hence a ruling can not be derived from it.
Firstly: Because the Prophet ﵆  has a specialty where some rules for him are different from the rest of the Ummah. Among these is that an ordinary person needs the consent of a woman's guardian to marry her, however the Prophet ﵆ does not legally require the consent of the woman's guardian since he himself is the foremost guardian of every Muslim. Hence this marriage does not provide evidence for who can be a valid guardian, as the marriage would be possible even if the guardian was not valid. Further her son was a minor at that time and a minor can not become a guardian according to the majority. Further she herself stated she does not have any guardian present. Hence it is argued that in the hadith Umm Salamah's son was asked to give her in marriage only as a gesture of kindness to please a child and not to satisfy any legal requirements.
Secondly: Her son was also her paternal relative as his father also belonged to the same clan as his mother and they shared an ancestor. It is possible that her son was her closest paternal relative who was present at that time, so this hadith would be covered in the exception mentioned above.
